# Windows are closed after unlocking

Tags: 14.04, unity, unlock

I've been using Ubuntu 14.04 for a long time. Recently when I lock my computer and unlock it after a while, Unity starts normal but all windows are closed.

I was willing to share some (actual) info, but could not figure out what is useful here. Any help would be appreciated.